# python backtrack

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

I have recently posted a few questions to understand recursion and backtrack, I felt I got something right now, and tried to write a test, I did solve the sudoku problem, but when I write the code in another format, the code stucks for a while and returns False, which indicates there are no solution to this problem.

grid is a 9x9 list of lists, if list[i][j] is zero then it means it needs to be filled in.

Here is the code which solved the problem:

```
def correct_solve(grid):

    # if there is no more zeros
    if found_solution(grid):
        return True

    for row in xrange(9):
        for col in xrange(9):
            if grid[row][col] == 0:
                for num in xrange(1, 10):
                    grid[row][col] = num
                    if check_sudoku(grid) == True:
                        if correct_solve(grid) == True:
                            return True
                # there are no numbers which could make
                # a valid solution, so backtrack
                grid[row][col] = 0
                return False
```

And here is another function which I tried to solve the problem in a different way, but it failed, and I couldn't find out where is the problem

```
def buggy_solve(grid, col):

    # if there is no more zeros
    if found_solution(grid):
        return True

    # if the col is over 8, make it to 0
    if col > 8:
        col = 0

    for row in xrange(9):
        if grid[row][col] == 0:
            for num in xrange(1, 10):
                grid[row][col] = num
                if check_sudoku(grid) == True:
                    # I tend to move to the next cell, and it seems that
                    # this is correct.
                    if buggy_solve(grid, col + 1) == True:
                        return True

            # if there are no valid solutions, backtrack.
            grid[row][col] = 0
            return False
```

I tried to debug the program and didn't found anything useful, btw is there any good practice to debug a piece of recursion code?

**EDIT:**

Here is the matrix I'm using to test:

```
easy = [[2,9,0,0,0,0,0,7,0],
        [3,0,6,0,0,8,4,0,0],
        [8,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,2],
        [0,2,0,0,3,1,0,0,7],
        [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,0,9,5,0,0,6,0],
        [7,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,1,2,0,0,3,0,6],
        [0,3,0,0,0,0,0,5,9]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`correct_solve` looks over all of the grid, while `buggy_solve` looks over a single column.  This means that, if the problem isn't solved yet, `buggy_solve` will only look in the current column for a cell to fill in -- if that column doesn't happen to have an empty cell, it will fall out of the outer for loop and exit, without using an explicit `return` statement.  So you'd need code to call `buggy_solve` on the next column when this happens (and use the appropriate `return` statement).

Comment: I did call `buggy_solve(grid, col + 1)` to move to the next column

Comment: @shengy: not if there is no row with a 0 in that column

Comment: Got it! I tried a grid which has a col 1 filled from 1 to 9 and the problem shows up. How did you find this problem in such a piece of recursive backtracking code? what is the best practice of debuging such programes?

Comment: In this case, by comparing correct_solve & buggy_solve, and recognizing that neither makes any progress until it finds a 0 to replace.

Comment: Can you help to correct the `buggy_solve`? I tried to add another `elif` but seems that it doesn't work

Comment: Seems that looking over the whole grid is the only solution, if I add something which let the program moves to another col, it actually is looking over the whole grid...

Comment: If you add return buggy_solve(grid,col+1) just after the row loop, it'll go to the next column if the current one has no 0's.  And why would you expect to be able to solve the problem WITHOUT going over the whole grid?

Comment: Um... seems that I got something wrong, thanks for helping me out for this:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your recursive solution never starts to backtrack. Instead it will end up in a endless recursion unless it will accidentally find a solution – which is very unlikely and only works for mostly solved sudokus. Taking those situations out, this is what is happening:

```
if buggy_solve(grid, col + 1) == True:
    return True
```

This `buggy_solve` call will *never* return false. Because the function will keep trying and iterating over the columns if necessary. And when it reaches the last column, it will start in the first again, overwriting everything that has happened before.

As such, the backtracking will never start. `check_sudoku` will rarely fail given that we’re still early in the processing and the mostly unfilled sudoku will probably allow multiple values in a given cell.

What you want to do is to prevent `buggy_solve` from starting all over, i.e. remove the column reset and make it simply return false for invalid columns. That way `buggy_solve` will return false at some point and the backtracking can actually start.

Comment: I degbuged `buggy_solve` and it did backtrack, I tried to input a grid which is all zeros. and seems that the program is backtracking correctlly